# Converting from one type to another that is nearly the same

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm passing a prop called defaultValue to a react component. The defaultValue has this typescript interface:

```
   interface IKeyValuePairProps {
      id: string;
      name: string;
    }
```

I pass it like this:

```
defaultValue={defaultValues && genes?.find((gene) => gene.id === defaultValues[0])}
```

Now genes is a interface that looks like this:

```
interface IGeneticMatchingGene {
  id: string;
  name?: string;
}
```

Now they are more og less the same. What is the best way to pass the default find result as IKeyValuePairProps?

Comment: Do you know for sure that there will be a value for `name`?

Comment: Yes, I dont know why the interface from the backend says name can be undefined.

Comment: The `?` after name means that it can be undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `as` to assert that the type is something else.

```
defaultValue={defaultValues && genes?.find((gene) => gene.id === defaultValues[0]) as IKeyValuePairProps}
```

Note that you should only use type assertions if you're sure that the type is correct.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions

Comment: I'm getting this error:
Type 'IKeyValuePairProps | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IKeyValuePairProps[] | undefined'.
  Type 'IKeyValuePairProps' is missing the following properties from type 'IKeyValuePairProps[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.

Comment: Fixed it. Hade IKeyValuePairProps[] in my child component